# Create Recurring Payment profile failed

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Hi All I am implementing recurring payments with paypal. My paypal script is already running now embedding recurring payments in it. I have searched a lot and not find any useful material. I found from [Recurring](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments#id08652L010BL) some material. I implemnted the code of createrecurringpayments.php from [here](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_php.txt) and changed the variables accorinding to mine. I redirect browser to this file from DoExpressCheckoutPayment.php when transaction is completed. But at createrecurringpayment.php I always get the following error.`CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile failed: Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2011%2d03%2d28T11%3a44%3a30Z [CORRELATIONID] => 81d0c488123c4 [ACK] => Failure [VERSION] => 54%2e0 [BUILD] => 1776465 [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002 [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security%20error [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )`.

Comment: hello, no body is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.... I was using paypal Express Checkout.. With this it is not possible to implement recurring payments...

Comment: You can do recurring payments via the express checkout with paypal. I am not sure if that was the case when you asked this question but I thought you might like to know.

Comment: @Sam Parmenter. Thanks boss. But I searched but didn't get any stuff related to it that how can I implement that. Would you like to tell me some related information?

Comment: Hey Buddy, have a look at this link. https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted and you will see that there is a menu item under the express checkout heading in the sidebar called "recurring payments". You can mix single payments and recurring payments pretty easily once you get your head round the whole thing.

Answer (score 3):

there may be below 4 causes for this type of error you found..

```
1. You have your PayPal module configured to "Sandbox" but have not used Sandbox API credentials.

2. You have your PayPal module configured to "Live" but have not used Live API credentials.

3. You have mis-typed one or more API credentials entries, including but not limited to leaving trailing spaces.

4. You have deleted and/or recreated new API credentials in your PayPal account but have not copied those new credentials back to your store.
```

Just check it out..it may helpful to you..

Thanks.